# Google Custom Search in Cyrillic

Tags: google-custom-search

I need some help with Cyrillic support. First, I do not know if it is possible but here it is what I want to do:

When typing in Google Custom Search is it possible letters to be changed automatically in Cyrillic characters? This actually should "replace" Alt+Shift function, so that user should not change his keyboard language and then start searching, but as he typing in the search letters should convert instantly.

Right now I am using "onkeyup="this.form.s.value=toCyr(this.form.s.value)" for my website and I was wondering if something similar could be done with Google Custom Search.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about replace , but google does have Phonetic typing which could be vary helpful http://www.google.com/inputtools/try/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this looks interesting. But the fact is that I can not see a way in which this input tools can be used with custom search. I believe I have tried everything, but simply there is no option from Google to use input tools with their custom search.